# return type xml or json in restful

Tags: java, xml

I have some code below, and when I test it with postman. It occurs an error "500". I don't understand the advantage of "@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)". Does it define return type automatically as XML, or not.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getUsers() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        return userDAO.getAllUsers();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gipxf/index.html

Comment: Yes, this indicates an XML returned type. Note to use the XML accept header at your postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//To process HTTP GET requests.
 @GET

//@Path Identifies the URI path that a resource class will serve requests for.
 @Path("/abcd")

//@Produces defines the media type(s) that the methods of a resource class can produce.
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML
```

I hope you have prepared the User class - with XmlRootElement and XML elements

for an example -

```
@XmlRootElement(name="User")
public class User{

    private int id;
    private String name; 

    public User() {

    }


    @XmlElement
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `@Produce` define the produced format. So your list of users will be format as XML.
Don't forget to parametrize Postman header to accept XML.

Answer (score 1):

It specifies the **content-types** (yes plural!) that this method produces (hence the name). This is used to

1. select the correct method to execute for an incoming request
2. determine what to produce as a response.

In your case when an incoming request needs JSON you will get a HTTP 406 as there is nothing that can handle this method.

Now if the method would have been annotated with `@Produces( {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON} )` it would be served and JSON would have been produced. Now you have single method serving both JSON and XML. What to serve is determined based on the `Accept-Header` of the incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

As your method, result return in xml format.